# Browser history from all signed-in devices is not getting in the chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I would like to create a chrome extension to fetch the browser history from all the signed-in devices. I use the chrome extension code as

```
chrome.history.search({
    'text': '', 
    'maxResults': 100000, 
    'startTime': 0
}, function(res){
      //code to write the data in an excel file
   }
```

Chrome history view (chrome://history/) shows history from all signed-in devices, but extension fetch only the history from local device (The device in which the extension runs). How can i fetch history from all devices? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ah, as I remember. this is not implemented yet.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry. This is not fixed yet.

See the bug: [Consider extending the chrome.history API to work with full synced history](http://crbug.com/474511)