# How to use chrome.history API to search urls that were done on mobile?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/history : Any suggestions on how to know if url in history was done on mobile or PC?

Answer (score 2):

I Believe you can't get that at present, according to the following, you could only get history from local device.

- [Browser history from all signed-in devices is not getting in the chrome extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33803207/browser-history-from-all-signed-in-devices-is-not-getting-in-the-chrome-extensio)
- https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=474511,

Comment: it's pretty annoying that they display one set of history items to the user in chrome://history, but return a subset of this on calls to the chrome.history api.